# directing output to both stdout and shared memory

Tags: c, vxworks

I am working on logging functionality in a embedded project in Vxworks in C.

Here we have shared memory where we write logs and read by another device.

Here I want all the output directed to both to shared memory and stdout i.e., serial console as well. How can we achieve this with out using any third party libraries in Vxworks  and using C language.

Thanks for your time and inputs.

Comment: Make your own `myprintf` function using functions of the `vprintf` family. Then replace all `printf` by `myprintf`. In the `myprintf` you write to the stdout and to whatever file, shared memory.... etc.

Comment: @Michel Walz. I am using existing project. problem is I cannot replace all existing printf. I want to some how redirect output using Vxworks API's for example. By the way you mentioned "myprintf function using functions of the vprintf family" request to give an example here or any link for beginners. Thanks

Comment: See my answer for an implementation of `myprintf`. Why is replacing `printf` by `myprintf` a problem ?

Comment: @venkysmarty: Your logging is probably done with a special function / macro already that adds timestamps, severity etc., no? Or do you really use `printf` for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace all `printf`s by `myprintf`(implementation below).

The `myprintf` function acts exactly as `printf` but does some further processing with the line.

```
void myprintf(const char *format, ...)
{
    char buffer[500];   // lines are restricted to maximum of 500 chars
    va_list args;
    va_start (args, format);
    vsnprintf (buffer, 500, format, args);
    va_end (args);

    // here buffer contains the string resulting from the invocation of myprintf
    // now here you can do whatever you want with the content of buffer

    puts(buffer);  // write to stdout

    ... code that writes the content of buffer to shared memory or whatever
}
```